# Javascript quiz - when user gets to the result, display a popup

Tags: javascript, popup

I have been researching on how to display a popup like the one in the image below yet I only found "Alert popup" or "Prompt popup" but that's not what I was looking for.

I want a popup that can be edited with html, I don't know how to explain it so I added an example below.

This website displays a popup after the user has finished the quiz. Then it displays social media buttons. I don't think that would be possible with an alert popup.

[image]

Results function:

```
function showFinalResults() {
  content.innerHTML = "<h3>WELL DONE!</h3>" +
 "<p>You're amazing for taking this quiz. Not many people challenge themselves every now and then. It's always good to stay confident with any challenges that may come your way.</p>" +
  "<h3>" + score + " out of " + quiz.length + " questions, " +
  Math.round(score / quiz.length * 100) + "%<h3>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my version of a popup window box thing:

You can use  `closepopup();` to close the window and `openpopup();` to open the window in javascript.

```js
function closepopup() {

  document.getElementById("alertbox").style.display = "none";
}


function openpopup() {

  document.getElementById("alertbox").style.display = "inline-block";
}



function showFinalResults() {
  openpopup();
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = score + " out of " + quiz.length + " questions, " + Math.round(score / quiz.length * 100) + "%";


}
```

```css
.alertbox {

          overflow: auto;

          float: left;

          width: 50vw;

          height: 68vh;

          background-color: white;

          display: hidden;

          position: absolute;

          z-index: 10;

          bottom: 16vh;

          left: 25vw;

          -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 4px black;

          -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 4px black;

          box-shadow: 0 3px 4px black;

        }

        .alertboxbar {

          width: 100%;

          height: 35px;

          background-color: #2196F3;

          margin-bottom: 10px;

        }

        .alertbartext {

          padding-left: 18px;

          padding-right: 18px;

          padding-bottom: 18px;

          font-size: 18px;

          -webkit-touch-callout: none;

          -webkit-user-select: none;

          -khtml-user-select: none;

          -moz-user-select: none;

          -ms-user-select: none;

          -o-user-select: none;

          user-select: none;

          pointer-events: none;

        }

        .alertbartitle {

          font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;

          font-size: 200%;

          color: black;

          padding-top: 10px;

          padding-left: 18px;

          padding-right: 18px;

          padding-bottom: 18px;

        }



        .closebutton {

          font-size: 35px;

          line-height: 35px;

          margin-left: calc(100% - 27px);

          margin-right: 12px;

          color: white;

          text-align: right;

          height: 100%;

          vertical-align: middle;

          text-decoration: none;

          cursor: default;

        }

        .closebutton:hover {

          color: #BDBDBD;

        }

#results {
  display: inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<div class="alertbox" id="alertbox">
  <div class="alertboxbar"><a onclick="closepopup()" class="closebutton">&times;</a>
  </div>
  <div class="alertbartitle">Well Done!
  </div>
  <div class="alertbartext">You're amazing for taking this quiz. Not many people challenge themselves every now and then. It's always good to stay confident with any challenges that may come your way.
    <br><br>
    You got: <div id="results"></div>
  </div>
```

You can add your own buttons etc. You may also want to add a `min-width` and `min-height` so it doesn't get too small!

Also when it is open it still interacts with all the other features... but I am sure you can post another question asking how to fix that if you so need.

Comment: This is great as well! Although, how would you go about displaying this after the user is done and has seen their results?

Comment: You use openpopup(); in javascript to display it. And you can use closepopup(); to close it!

Comment: I am not familiar with Javascript that much. I'm kind of lost

Comment: @Martin Okay I have edited my code... If you add it to your site it should work... I have changed your javascript that you put in your post, and exchanged it with my mine.. when you test my code.. keep a backup of what you have in case it doesn't work!

Comment: I added this and the popup displays right away when the user navigates to the quiz

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107393/discussion-between-martin-and-trevor-clarke).

Comment: @Martin Send me a link to a chat room

Answer (score 1):

There is many way to create a popup like you want.

1. From scratch, you have to use your "HTML and CSS"-fu :

   - create a Div element for the background overlay that match the whole page. With CSS set the opacity property to fit the right look,
   - create a Div element to create the popup called *modal box*. Center it with some appropriate CSS.
   - inside of this Div, add a button or a link to close the box. This is commonly a good ergonomic pratice,
   - Set the close strategy for clicks triggered out of the modal box. For example, do you want the modal box closable when you click on the overlay or not.

Edit: Here's a good tutorial who explain perfectly how to create a modal box from scratch : http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/

2. Take a look at those Javascript frameworks :

   - http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals
   - https://jqueryui.com/dialog/
   - http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/dialog